# @media print and (orientation:portrait) does not work if (orientation:landscape) is also specified

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm trying to make a div which takes 100% of A4 page when printing, no matter if you choose portrait or landscape in the print dialog window.

**test.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" type="text/css"/>
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**test.css**

```
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

@media print and (orientation: portrait) {
    .page {
        height: 297mm;
        width: 210mm;
        background: red;
    }
}

@media print and (orientation: landscape) {
    .page {
        height: 210mm;
        width: 297mm;
        background: red;
    }
}
```

Expected: the div will take 100% of the A4 page in the print preview in both landscape and portrait mode.

Actual: the div takes 100% of the page only in the landscape mode. In portrait mode it takes only like 60% of the page.

If I specify `height: 420mm;width: 300mm;` for portrait mode, it takes 100% of the page in both modes, but it doesn't seem like a proper solution.

If I just remove the landscape rule, the div starts to take 100% of the page in portrait mode.

The browser is Chrome 54.0.2840.100 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 16.04.

Why this code does not work as expected and how to achieve the expected result?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and solved like this :

for landscape oriented print :

```
@media print {...}
```

and for portrait oriented print :

```
@media print and (max-width: 40em) {...}
```

I hope someone found a cleaner solution.